# I dont stay in the US. Can I create and distribute my own version of Monopoly that is personalized for my city?

Tags: monopoly, copyright

I would like to change mostly the names, currency etc and make it relatable to my city here in Africa. Will the US Company sue me for distributing the game in my local town? Also i wanted to understand if the name "Monopoly" is a trade name or if its just the name of the game.

Comment: Maybe this should be on the Law.SE.

Answer (score 4):

The vast majority of countries in the world are either signatories to the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) or the [TRIPS Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIPS_Agreement), both of which ensure that copyright is protected in those jurisdictions. As such, what you're suggesting is a copyright violation and could definitely lead to legal difficulties for you.

> Will the US Company sue me for distributing the game in my local town?

We can't tell you Hasbro will do about a small scale copyright violation. They certainly *have* taken legal action to protect their brand in the past though.

> Also i wanted to understand if the name "Monopoly" is a trade name or if its just the name of the game.

Monopoly is a registered trade mark in both the US and the UK, and [has been successfully defended in both jurisdictions](https://grr.com/publications/monopoly-trademark-hasbros-monopoly/) (after a change to the primary legislation in the US). For other jurisdictions, you will probably need to do your own research.

Comment: You typically cant copyright the rules to a game. It doesnt sound like OP wants to take artwork or names that could be covered. What specifically are you saying violates copyright?

Comment: www.custommonopoly.com
this site seems to sell custom monopoly sets so you might be able to order your product through them
also you can buy this official product on amazon:
https://www.amazon.com/Make-Your-Opoly-Board-Game/dp/B00000K2IO